How to add a generic credential for a specific Windows User using Powershell and a Pipeline
I'd like to add a generic credential to the Credential Manager on a Windows VM using a Powershell script which is executed by conducting a GitHub Action workflow.

The credential has to be added for a specific Windows User.
I tried it using PSexec like:
 $psexec -u <username of my windows user> -p "<password of my windows user>" cmdkey /add /generic:<name> /user:<username> /pass:"<password>"

or
cmdkey /generic:<name> /user:<username> /pass:<password>

and running command above with the dedicated Windows user.
But it seems, the credential is always created in the SYSTEM context, so it's not created for this dedicated user.
Any ideas, how I can create a generic credential for a specific Windows user, using a GitHub Action Workflow (shouldn't matter whether ADO, Gitlab, GitHub,...) and Powershell?
Thanks in advance!

You need to use Run As if you are trying to as another user and need to be an Admin.  You are only getting the credentials of another user and not running the script as another user.

Tried that, didn't work, still created the credential in the context of the System user

What is the real issue?  Does it make a difference if the credentials have a System Permission?  As long as the credentials are recognized by the server as valid the owner of the credentials do not make a difference.

Try invoke-command -computername <remotecomputer> -scriptblock {cmdkey /generic:<name> /user:<username> /pass:<password>} -credential (get-credential) and when prompted, type in the credential for the remote computer to add the credential within their Windows profile. Just an idea to try so dropping as a comment to start. @bianconero

Try using the -i switch with PSExec - so that it does an interactive logon instead of a network logon? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/securing-privileged-access/reference-tools-logon-types

@Minkus thx for your approach, unfortunately it didn't work either...

@BitcoinMurderousManiac thx for that, but this would mean to have a manual step, which shouldn't be the case - or am I wrong?

@jdweng I'm not 100% sure, but I got the instruction, that the credential has to be set by a specifc Windows user...

Let's have a different perspective: how would you automate the creation of a generic credential for a specific Windows user? Without having e.g.: an interactive  PowerShell session?

Why do you think it is a credential issue?  We really don't know even why you are trying to get the credential.  Is the credential needed?  What error are you getting?  Is there a route to the domain server which has the credentials?

@jdweng Yes, the credential is needed for an application. I think I'll try to see whether this application (legacy application) is capable of reading the credentials from the System context, it seems there is no solution

Thx to all for the suggestions!
